# Is argmin of a sum of two functions equal to sum of each argmin?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, fractional-calculus

**Problem:** Given function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, convex; function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is nongegative, convex and $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is positive, convex. Consider the following problem
$$\overline\theta = \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\dfrac{g(x)}{h(x)}.$$
To solve the above problem, we can solve problem $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\left\{g(x) - \overline\theta h(x)\right\}$ instead.

So to solve $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}f(x) +\dfrac{g(x)}{h(x)}$, we can solve the following problem instead or not?
$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\left\{f(x) + g(x) - \overline\theta h(x)\right\}$$

Comment: See the counterexample in my response.  In addition, you can see that when all functions are differentiable, the first order conditions of $\min g/h$ and $\min g-\bar\theta h$ are identical by the quotient rule.  However, the first order conditions of $\min f+g/h$ and $\min f+g-\bar \theta h$ are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x)=-x,g(x)=(1+x^2)^2,h(x)=1+x^2$. Then
$$\bar \theta=\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left\{\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}=1+x^2\right\}= 1,\\
\arg\min_{x\in\mathbb{R} }\left\{f(x)+\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}=x^2-x+1\right\}=\frac{1}{2},\\
\arg\min_{x\in\mathbb{R} }\left\{f(x)+g(x)-\bar\theta h(x)=x^4+x^2-x\right\}\neq \frac{1}{2}.\\
$$